# Is it bad practice to use temporary tables in SQL?

Tags: sql

That is, using temporary tables with some initial unique data and then populating it one or several fields at a time. Sometimes it makes code seem more readable but it also leads to procedural type thinking. And it's also slower than using derived tables or other methods. Is it discouraged in industry?

Comment: @Quassnoi: I'm thinking of usage of temp tables in T-SQL/PL-SQL/etc. in UDFs and stored procs and not in the set-based manner. That's why i wanted to see an example.

Comment: @Paul: `TSQL` and `PL/SQL` are procedural languages which can embed declarative `SQL` statements. You should not be confused by `SQL` in their names.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Not confused about their relationship to SQL. I simply made the assumption (perhaps poorly) that the OP was thinking of using temp tables via the procedural capabilities of particular SQL implementations. I should have asked for clarification first.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It would be a bad practice if all set-based operations were a) implemented and b) efficiently in all engines.

However, for some tasks (like emulating `LAG` and `LEAD` in `SQL Server`, long insert chains on cascading auto-generated `id` is several tables etc), temp tables or table variables are a nice solution.

You should note that temporary tables are very often created and dropped by the engine itself for the operations involving `using temporary` in `MySQL`, `spool` in `SQL Server` etc.

So each time you create a temp table you should ask yourself a question:

- Do I create a temp table because I don't know a set-based way, or because I know a set-based way but the server (or optimizer) does not?

If the answer is "I know but the optimizer does not", then create the table. The optimizer would do the same if it could.